# Windows 'gcloud init' returns C:\Program is not recognized, Python was not found (but Python works on cmd)

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I'm trying to get Google Cloud SDK working on my Windows 10 desktop, but when I use the SDK shell (which, as I understand it, is just command line but with the directory changed to where Cloud SDK is installed), running 'gcloud init' returns the following:

'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
'""C:\Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.

It then finishes the configuration and tells me 'Your Google Cloud SDK is configured and ready to use!' However, whenever I run any other commands, I get the same error popup again before it continues doing whatever the command does. I believe Python is installed correctly and added to Path, and when I call python from the same command line, same directory as my 'gcloud init' call, it functions as expected and opens a python console. Any ideas at what the problem might be? (or if it will even affect anything?)

Comment: 1) Show the command that generated the error. Also, use the question text formatting options so that error messages can be read easily. 2) The error is caused by the PATH environment variable being messed up. Add to your question the output from this command `echo %PATH%` when run in a Command Prompt. 3) The Google Cloud CLI does not need Python, it includes its own version. Do not deselect it when installing. 4) My advice is to uninstall the CLI, reboot your system, fix the PATH environment variable, reboot, and install again.

Comment: reinstalling using the built-in python seems to have worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to -> "start" and type "Manage App Execution Aliases". Go to it and turn off "Python"